# Declaring a variable inside a if else statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I'm still very new to Java programming so I have a question.
Can I declare a variable inside a if-else statement, just like a for loop?

```
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)



    int test;
    if (test=6;test ==9;) {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
```

Comment: Well, why don't you try and see? If the compiler complains, then what you're doing isn't right.

Comment: Is the code right for the if statement? The "test == 9;" or it should just be "test == 9"?

Comment: You can use the bitwise inclusive OR |
logical AND

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't do that.  The stuff inside the round brackets in an `if` statement must be a single expression that delivers a `boolean` value.  A variable declaration is never an expression in Java.

Assuming that you are trying to declare `test` so that its scope is limited to the if/else statement, then this is how to do it:

```
public void someMethod() {
    ....
    { // nested block to limit the scope of 'test'
        int test = 6;
        if (test == 9) {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No");
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>(The example doesn't make much sense, but I assume that it is not meant to.)</sup>

Comment: Wow, didn't know you could have nested blocks inside a method. Is there any disadvantage to them, or are they just a scope-limiting mechanism without any other effects?

Comment: There is no performance disadvantage.  I guess they can detract from readability.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
if (test=6;test ==9;) {
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No");
    }
```

you can not have semicolons inside `if()`

The way you are doing is called initialization (`test=6;`) which is not allowed.You can just compare 2 variables inside if like `if(test==6)`

Remeber that `java` `If` accepts only `boolean` that are `true` or `false` (not like in javascript which accepts anything greater than 1)

Comment: So it means I cannot declare variables inside a if-else statement?

Comment: @user3744056 the way you are doing is called initialization `test=6` you can not initialize inside if

Comment: Wait what, initialization is *definitely* allowed inside an `if` statement. See [here](http://ideone.com/jqLnFP). It actually be the source of bugs because programmers accidentally assign instead of compare.

Comment: @user3744056 You cannot *declare* variables inside an `if` statement. You can, however, *assign* to one.

Comment: @user3580294 ohh come one you can do that for int or anything other than boolean http://ideone.com/fork/sk4kDj

Comment: Yes, you can (although it'd be a compilation error for anything other than a `boolean`). What's your point?

Comment: @user3580294 but you said *initialization is definitely allowed inside an if statement* so I said its not allowed and gave an example.This is what I wanted to say

Comment: Initialization is allowed inside an `if` statement, period. I showed an example where it is allowed. It compiles, and it's allowed by the JLS. There's no doubt about that. What is *not* allowed is initialization of a variable *that isn't a `boolean` variable*. And that is *not* what I said. Initialization is allowed. Initialization of a variable of the incorrect type isn't. But that does *not* mean initialization isn't allowed at all.

Comment: @user3580294 And I said initialization is not allowed(and my example is based on int because OP also uses int in his `if` ) so I said initialization is not allowed.If OP would have Used boolean then we would have answered for boolean but OP uses int and it does not make any sense to give answers in boolean

Comment: Your statement is too broad. You're saying that initialization isn't allowed, which is patently false. You need to say that initialization of a variable *that isn't a `boolean`* isn't allowed or something of the sort, or something like "initialization isn't allowed *in this case*. Those extra words would limit the scope of your statement so it isn't wrong any more. It doesn't matter what your statement is based on if you say something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The expression in condition or decision making statements in java must evaluate to a boolean value (true/false).  Even the following cases won't compile:

```
if(null){}
if(0){}
```

and so on.